# C# UserControl Button click adds items to listbox from form1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a C# app,that searches for song names on youtube (using youtube api) and displaying the data, I have a custom SongItem (UserControl) and I add them to a FlowLayoutControl. I added a "Favourite" button to the UserControl, and I need that to add itself to another FlowLayoutControl that's the Favourited song list, but I can't get that working, I can't have multiple base classes in the UserControl,and adding a public method to Form1, doesn't solve my issue, (it's not adding anything,tried it with listbox,but nothing).
I'm really stuck here,if someone can at least suggest something I would rly appreciate it.

Here is my SongItem

```
[Serializable]
public partial class SongItem : UserControl,Form
{
    private String songName = "Song Name";
    private String artistName = "Artist Name";
    private Image thumbNail;
    private String length;
    private int maxLengthSongName = 25;
    private int maxLengthArtistName = 25;
    private Color colorHoverOn = Color.FromArgb(53,53,53);
    private Color colorNormal = Color.FromArgb(53,53,53);
    private SongData songData;
    public SongItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseClick += Control_MouseClick;
        MouseEvents(this);
    }
    private void SongItem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LoadData();
        }
        catch { }
        LoadDataToUI();

    }

    #region GettersAndSetters

    public int MaxLengthSongName
    {
        get { return maxLengthSongName; }
        set { maxLengthSongName = value; }
    }
    public int MaxLengthArtistName
    {
        get { return maxLengthArtistName; }
        set { maxLengthArtistName = value; }
    }

    public Color ColorHoverOn
    {
        get { return colorHoverOn; }
        set { colorHoverOn = value; }
    }
    public Color ColorNormal
    {
        get { return colorNormal; }
        set { colorNormal = value; }
    }

    public SongData SongData {
        get{return songData; }
        set { songData = value; } 
    }
    #endregion

    public void LoadData()
    {
        songName = songData.SongName;
        artistName = songData.ArtistName;
        thumbNail = songData.ThumbNail;
        length = songData.Length;
    }

    void MouseEvents(Control container)
    {
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseEnter += (s, e) => SongItem_MouseEnter(e);
            c.MouseLeave += (s, e) => SongItem_MouseLeave(e);
            c.MouseClick += Control_MouseClick;
            MouseEvents(c);
        };
    }


    private void SongNameLbl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (songName.Length > maxLengthSongName) {
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(songNameLbl, songName);
        }
    }

    private void ArtistNameLbl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (artistName.Length > maxLengthArtistName) {
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(artistNameLbl, artistName);
        }
    }

    private void SongNameLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(artistName + " " +songName);
    }

    #endregion

    #region CurrentlySelected
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> WasClicked;

    private void Control_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var wasClicked = WasClicked;
        if (wasClicked != null)
        {
            WasClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        IsSelected = true;
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.BorderStyle = IsSelected ? BorderStyle.FixedSingle : BorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    private void Fovourite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main newMain = new Main();
       // newMain.AddSongToFavorite();
        newMain.listBox1.Items.Add("Test");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the the Form1 code

```
public void AddSongToFavorite() {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Test");
        //songList2.AddSong("Dire Straits - Sultans Of Swing");
        MessageBox.Show("Hello", "Test");
       // flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(song);
    }
```

Message shows up,but nothing else

I add the SongItem from another class

```
 public partial class SongList : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public SongList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SongList_Load();
    }

    private void SongList_Load()
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.WrapContents = false;
    }

    public async void AddSong(String songName) {
        SongData song = await YoutubeSearch.GetSongInfo(songName);
       // SongData song = XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<SongData>(Application.StartupPath + @"\test.txt");
        SongItem songItem = new SongItem { SongData = song };
        songItem.WasClicked += UsersGrid_WasClicked;
        this.Controls.Add(songItem);
    }
```

Comment: How are you instatiating SongItem in Form1? Also, how are you passing trying to pass UI objects like listbox1? With the provided code, it looks like you are creating a new separate form.

Comment: I edited the question,I don't want to create another form, I was just searching on Google on how to edit elements from another forms,but it was dead end.From Form1 I just call the AddSong() from the SongList class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating an EventHandler

In the main I created this public void

```
public void FavoriteWasClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (sender is SongItem)
        {
            songList2.AddSong(((SongItem)sender).SongData);
        }
    }
```

and on Form1 load I added (songList1 is the FlowLayoutPanel already added in the Form1 designer)

```
songList1.List_FavoriteWasClicked += FavoriteWasClicked;
```

I added this line to the FlowLayoutPanel class I created

```
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs> List_FavoriteWasClicked;
```

and when creating new Controls(SongItems inside it)(Still part of FlowLayoutPanel)

```
 public void AddSong(SongData song)
    {
        SongItem songItem = new SongItem { SongData = song };
        songItem.FavoriteWasClicked += List_FavoriteWasClicked; ()
        this.Controls.Add(songItem);
    }
```

And now on the SongItem I created the custom event

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FavoriteWasClicked;
```

and on the button I wanted to be the press to add to favorite list I added the following

```
 FavoriteWasClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Now when I press the button to add one Song to the liked/favorited list it's actually adding it.